# Replace a whole word containing a pattern - gsub and R

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I am trying to clean some garbage out of some text. While doing this, I am assuming that any word that has a letter (any letter) repeated three or more times is garbage - and I want to remove it.

I've come up with this:

```
gsub(pattern = "[a-zA-Z]\\1\\1", replacement = "", string)
```

in which `string` is the character vector, but this doesn't work. Everything else I've tried might find the pattern, but it just removes the pattern, leaving a mess. I'm trying to remove the whole word with the pattern in it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```r
gsub("\\s*[[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]])\\1{2}[[:alpha:]]*", "", string)
gsub("\\s*\\p{L}*(\\p{L})\\1{2}\\p{L}*", "", string, perl=TRUE)
stringr::str_replace_all(string, "\\s*\\p{L}*(\\p{L})\\1{2}\\p{L}*", "")
```

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/QSDY1Q):

```r
string <- "This is a baaaad unnnnecessary short word"
gsub("\\s*[[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]])\\1{2}[[:alpha:]]*", "", string)
gsub("\\s*\\p{L}*(\\p{L})\\1{2}\\p{L}*", "", string, perl=TRUE)
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(string, "\\s*\\p{L}*(\\p{L})\\1{2}\\p{L}*", "")
```

All yielding `[1] "This is a short word"`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JLwsyY/2). **Regex details**:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\p{L}*` / `[[:alpha:]]*` - zero or more letters
- `(\p{L})` - Capturing group 1: any single letter
- `\1{2}` - two occurrences of the same value as in Group 1
- `\p{L}*` / `[[:alpha:]]*` - zero or more letters.

Comment: This was excellent, but it failed to find strings like "AAA" (by itself without quotes), "BBB", or "DDd". Any thoughts?

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg If you mean the backreference must be case insensitive, use [this code](https://ideone.com/MO8ZvY).

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a "capture group" to the `[.]` class by wrapping it in parens, since the `\\1` needs something to reference:

```r
gsub("([a-zA-Z])\\1\\1", "", "aabbbccdddee")
# [1] "aaccee"
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated on OP comment:
Try this:

```
gsub("([A-Z]&|[a-z])\\1{2, }", "", "AAA")
[1] "AAA"
gsub("([A-Z]&|[a-z])\\1{2, }", "", "aabbbccdddee")
[1] "aaccee"
```

r2evans example with different regex:

```
gsub("(\\w)\\1{2, }", "", "aabbbccdddee")
```

```
[1] "aaccee"
```